# Django admin site redirecting to wrong location

Tags: django, aws-lambda, django-admin, amazon-cloudfront, python-zappa

I have a Django app, being deployed to Amazon Lambda using `zappa`. The admin routes are registered under `/api`, and when deployed, they get further deployed to `/int`, so the admin site is available under `/int/api/admin/`.

However, this site is served from CloudFront, which takes requests to `/api` and proxies them to `/int/api`. When I hit `/api/admin/` on CloudFront, it requests `/int/api/admin/` from my Lambda instance, and that sends a redirect to `/int/api/admin/login` which fails.

How do I fix this?